# height computation with ie11

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 divs, in a 2x2, and the height of the 4th div is calculated as such:

4th.style.height = 2nd.offsetHeight + 1st.offsetHeight - 3rd.offsetHeight.

The first 3 div's heights are calculated based off of their content.

In firefox and chrome, this works as expected. However, in IE 11 it only works sometimes. As the browser width increases (and thus the heights of the other divs change), sometimes it will line up perfectly, and sometimes the right column (Divs 3 and 4) will be pushed down a small amount. I logged all the heights to the console, and then changed the browser size a tiny amount toggling between it working and not working, and the log was that all 4 heights stayed the same?? I am prone to think that there is simply a rounding error going on here, but I am quite confused.

Comment: Can you share the relevant markup and the styles applied to the 4 divs?

Comment: The markup and styles are relatively complicated to be honest, I am working on a plunker at the moment, but plunker doesn't seem to work very well with IE